# Can I (temporarily) host an MS Access application on Azure?

Tags: azure, ms-access

My client has an MS Access split database and will lose access to their in-house servers for 2 weeks to a month.

I'm thinking about building an Azure windows server and putting the back-end there, then having clients (about 12 of them) use RDP to sessions on that server (making sure that they each have the latest copy of the front-end in their own sessions).

I realize this is an "opinion" question - perhaps someone can point me to an appropriate forum - if not here.

Comment: Of course you can do that. But Azure is quite expensive, you can consider asphostportal.com if you want as your alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that. Any (virtual) machine running an Access database and allowing RDP access can be reached via Remote Desktop.

You may need a *Terminal Server* license for multiple simultaneous users.